# using group by and showing-hiding the group div for selected checkbox

Tags: angularjs

I need to be able to group check boxes based on their categories and show only the group from which items have been selected and hide others.

But as per my code , it shows and hides but checks all check boxes of selected category.ow do I modify it to fix this issue?

I understand it is because of what i am returning but h

Here is what I have:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="dataController">
<div>
<!--<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in properties | groupBy: 'name'" ng-show='(properties |  filter: filterByCategory)'">-->
 <ul ng-repeat="(key,value) in filtered=(properties  | filter:filterByCategory| groupBy: 'name') ">

  <li>Group name: <strong>{{ key }}</strong></li>

          <div  ng-repeat="prop in value">
            <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter[key]"/>
                        <span>{{prop.Property}}</span>
            </label>
          </div>
 </ul>
```

JS:

```
$scope.filter = {};
$scope.filterByCategory = function (prop) {



        return $scope.filter[prop.name] || noFilter($scope.filter);
    };

     function noFilter(filterObj) {
        for (var key in filterObj) {

            if (filterObj[key]) {

                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `ng-repeat` your checkboxes over `prop in value`, but use the grouped `key` for the checkbox `ng-model`.

This means all your checkboxes of a group share the same `ng-model` expression and thus the same scope property - checking one will of course check all the others.

I can't really tell what you are trying to achieve with your filter object, but you will need to use separate `ng-model` expressions for your checkboxes to let them have separate states.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly the problem.